# Redirecting to previous page after Auth0 sign-in

Tags: reactjs, react-router, auth0

Upon entering a protected route the user gets redirected to auth0 as follows:

`/user/home -> auth0 login -> /user/home`

or

`/user/profile/id123 -> auth0 login -> /user/home`

but always to the callback url (`/user/home` in this case)

Using the following code

```
function Auth0RedirectWrapper(props: { children: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment; }) {
 
// redirects user to an Auth0 sign-in page with 'http://localhost:3000/user/home' as callback 

}

function Profile() {
    let params = useParams();
    return(<p>Profile of {params.userId}<p/>)
}

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
                <Route element={<Auth0RedirectWrapper><Outlet /></Auth0RedirectWrapper>} >
                    <Route path='/user/home' element={<p>Welcome home </>} />
                    <Route path='/user/profile/:userId' element={<Profile/>} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

The question: **what is the prefered method of always redirecting to the page a user visited initially?**

e.g. `/user/profile/id123 -> auth0 login -> /user/home` would become `/user/profile/id123 -> auth0 login -> /user/profile/id123`

Using:

- ReactJs
- Auth0
- React-router v6
- [Auth0-react](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-react/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is saving the currentpage in the `localStorage`. Then set the callback to a designated url `\redirectAfterLogin`. When visiting `\redirectAfterLogin` use react-router's `Navigate` component to redirect to the page saved in `localStorage`.

```
function Auth0RedirectWrapper(props: { children: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment; }) {
 
// redirects user to an Auth0 sign-in page with 'http://localhost:3000/redirectAfterLogin' as callback 

}

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <RedirectingRouter />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

function RedirectingRouter() {

    //save previous path so that we can return to it after auth0 authentication
    let location = useLocation();
    let [prevPath, setPrevPath] = useState(localStorage.getItem('prevPage'));

    useEffect(() => {
        setPrevPath(localStorage.getItem('prevPage'));
        if (location.pathname !== '/redirectAfterLogin') localStorage.setItem('prevPage', location.pathname)
    }, [location])

    return (

        <Routes>
            <Route element={<Auth0RedirectWrapper><Outlet /></Auth0RedirectWrapper>} >
                <Route path='/redirectAfterLogin' element={<Navigate to={prevPath ? prevPath : '/user/home'} replace />} />
                    <Route path='/user/home' element={<p>Welcome home </>} />
                    <Route path='/user/profile/:userId' element={<Profile/>} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
    )
}
```